# Remove '&' sign from string automatically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sending a string through JavaScript, but the problem is that it removes the '&' sign automatically. Before the [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request I have got the string perfectly, but on the server side I don't get any '&' in the string.

```
var user = 1; // ex: user_id
var message = "I like cricket & football"; // Example: message
var dataString = "user"=+ user + "&msg=" + message;
alert(message); // It shows my string perfectly: I like cricket & football
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:dataString,
    url:  rootPath()+"user/reply_msg_user",
    success: function(data){}
});
```

After sending the datastring by the Ajax request on the server side it only shows:

> I like cricket football

Comment: URLencode the string.

Comment: thanks, its working @AdamAzad

Comment: Top posting tips: no need to apologise for your English - these phrases are just clutter and will probably be edited out anyway. Also, please don't request urgency, if only to avoid downvotes - [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @halfer

Comment: @PeterMortensen: minor point of style. I'd already corrected `ajax` to `AJAX`, which seems to be acceptable according to the Wikipedia article. I don't mind it being edited again, but it's probably worth only correcting these things if they are wrong (as the lower case version would be). Good edits otherwise though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var message = encodeURIComponent('I like cricket & football');
```